# Help with understanding a regular expression

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression

I have this regular expression  `\\..\\{3\\}$`

I want to understand how this expression works to match a string. My thought is that it matches any 8 characters at the end of the line. Is that how this expression works?

If so, I think something like this would match the string:

`rs.efg$tu`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming "typical" regexp's (sadly, different tools handle slightly different rexexps, and the GNU and POSIX versions are also different, and then there has been some version drift...), this parses as [Need Unicode-Art in markup...]

```
\.  . \{3\} $
 ▲  ▲   ▲   ▲
 │  │   │   │
 │  │   │   └─ End of line
 │  │   └─ Preceding exactly 3 times (the '\' makes '{' special...)
 │  └─ Any character (except '\n')
 └─ A literal '.' ('.' is special, '\' makes it un-special)
```

So this means a dot and 3 random characters before the end of the line.

Constructions like `*` or `\{3\}` (if the last one is even supported) apply to the last character, or the last parentesis (probably `\( ... \)`, but that is again regexp-dialect-dependent). Check the manual *for the exact tool you are using*.

Comment: This not quite right. His first `.` is escaped, so it is a literal `.`. Good ASCII breakdown though.

Comment: I see I forgot that the first . was escape so I counted that in during the process of matching character, thank you very much

Comment: Strange... I swear I didn't see that. Fixing. Thanks!

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the initial backslash.